# Returning matching attribute value from xpath sequence

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to get an attribute value from the list of values returned by the below query :-

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";
 let $bkp_location := xdmp:filesystem-directory("/etc/")//dir:entry/dir:pathname/string(fn:ends)
 return $bkp_location
```

The above query returns three values

```
/etc/users
/etc/readme/file-permission
/etc/recovery-failures
```

I want to capture only the /etc/readme/file-permission into a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: First of all, you use the word "attribute", and with XML that means something particular. Since you are returning a sequence of strings, I assume you just mean that you are looking for one particular item in the sequence, and it has nothing to do with XML attributes. Do you know ahead of time that you want `/etc/readme/file-permission`? Are you just looking to test that it exists?

Comment: Second, in your code you have `string(fn:ends)`. That doesn't seem right. Were you trying to filter with `fn:ends-with()` or is there something else you were selecting for the string value to return?

Comment: Hi, i am trying to just capture the "/etc/readme/file-permission in a variable and i am unable to do it using fn:ends-with()

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find the file(s) that [`ends-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-ends-with) "permission", you could apply a predicate to filter that sequence of paths:

```
xdmp:filesystem-directory("/etc/")//dir:entry/dir:pathname/string()[ends-with(., "permission"]
```

If you were simply applying `ends-with()` as the last step of your XPath, then it would return the boolean value, rather than use it to filter the sequence.

You could also use a for loop and test if `ends-with()` in a `where` clause in your FLWOR:

```
for $path in xdmp:filesystem-directory("/etc/")//dir:entry/dir:pathname/string()
where ends-with($path, "permission"]
return $path
```